# How can I get client variable inside a slashcommand execute function?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like my bot to reply to a slash command by sending a message to a specified channel. However, every example I have seen only sends these messages through the `client.on()` or `client.once()` functions where they pass in the client as a parameter, then use `client.channels.cache.get('channel_ID')`.

My `execute(interaction)` function for this command takes the interaction as a parameter instead. I do know I can pull the channel_id of the interaction from `interaction.channel_id`, but then it seems like I still have to `get` a handle on that channel through the client.

Can I pass in the client and the interaction when executing slash command functions? Is there another way to get a handle on the channel in order to send to it without using client?

Answer (score 1):

All Discord.js classes have an internal `client` property, so for you all you need to access is `interaction.client`.